# How to output secret uri in ARM template?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-resource-manager

I am unable to output the secret URI from my secret resource in my ARM template.
Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean you want to have it from the KeyVault, try this:

```
"outputs":{
"mySecretUri": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', parameters('keyVaultName'), parameters('mySecretName'))).secretUri]"
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case the secret is a generated value which changes with every ARM deployment.

This requires the specification of the secrets' version number:

```
"value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', parameters('vaultName'), parameters('secrets_secretName'))).secretUriWithVersion]"
```